# nginx don't reconoize subdomain, it redirect to default page always

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I have a problem with setting nginx:

I have a subdomain on goDaddy: allies.ejample.com.co
On digitalOcean I have nginx with this server block

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/allies;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name allies.example.com.co www.allies.example.com.co;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

when I type in browser allies.example.com.co it redirect to default page into /var/www/html into this folder is default page of nginx.

What do I am wrong ?? ...

Somebody Can help me?

Comment: You should put your site configurations inside sites-available folder. To enable a configuration, you should symlink it to sites-enabled folder and restart nginx instance.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to see the entire configuration that Nginx is using. Do you see your `server` block there?